# Why is my Java logger file not working?

Tags: java

I am using Java's built in logger for this example. It was writing to my log file but it is not now.

**Question: Why is my file not being written to?**

I pasted all of the code here so that if someone wanted to try it it would be an easy copy and paste. But the logger lines are in the constructor.

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FileChooserDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static private final String newline = "\n";
    JButton openButton;
    JButton saveButton;
    JTextArea log;
    JFileChooser fc;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileChooserDemo.class.getName());
    FileHandler fh;   

    public FileChooserDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); 
            fh = new FileHandler("C:\\Users\\itpr13266\\Desktop\\MyNewLogFile.log");   
            logger.info("Logging an INFO-level message");
            logger.warning("Your file cannot be written!!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileChooserDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        log = new JTextArea(5,20);
        log.setMargin(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
        log.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane logScrollPane = new JScrollPane(log);

        fc = new JFileChooser();

        openButton = new JButton("Open a File...");
        openButton.addActionListener(this);

        saveButton = new JButton("Save a File...");
        saveButton.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); //use FlowLayout
        buttonPanel.add(openButton);
        buttonPanel.add(saveButton);

        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(logScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                log.append("Opening: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
            } else {
                log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
            }
            log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
        } else if (e.getSource() == saveButton) {
            int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                log.append("Saving: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
            } else {
                log.append("Save command cancelled by user." + newline);
            }
            log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
        }
    }

    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = FileChooserDemo.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileChooserDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new FileChooserDemo());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createAndShowGUI();
     }
}
```

Log printout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
<record>
  <date>2014-05-12T10:30:00</date>
  <millis>1399908600500</millis>
  <sequence>0</sequence>
  <logger>TestMenu.FileChooserDemo</logger>
  <level>INFO</level>
  <class>TestMenu.FileChooserDemo</class>
  <method>&lt;init&gt;</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Logging an INFO-level message</message>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2014-05-12T10:30:00</date>
  <millis>1399908600517</millis>
  <sequence>1</sequence>
  <logger>TestMenu.FileChooserDemo</logger>
  <level>WARNING</level>
  <class>TestMenu.FileChooserDemo</class>
  <method>&lt;init&gt;</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Your file cannot be written!!</message>
</record>
</log>
```

Comment: Could you please show your log configuration?

Comment: You should try to isolate the problem by writing a simpler example that is just a `main() { Log.info("something"); }`. That will remove unnecessary information from your question and narrow down what needs to be investigated.

Comment: Were do you find the log configuration. Is this a test file like Log4J is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you are adding the `FileHandler fh` you created to your `Logger logger`

```
logger.addHandler(fh);
```

Your log is probably being written but not in the place you attempted to specify.

```
fh = new FileHandler("C:\\Users\\itpr13266\\Desktop\\MyNewLogFile.log");   
logger.addHandler(fh);
logger.info("Logging an INFO-level message");
logger.warning("Your file cannot be written!!");
```